# Speeding up partition_point-based search

Tags: rust, lookup, vec

I've been recently doing a collection of lookups of indices that satisfy a given criterion as follows,

```
some_vector.partition_point(|x| x < &el)
```

In a loop that does millions of lookups

```
for el in elements {
    let iloc = some_vector.partition_point(|x| x < &el);
    some_other_vec.push(iloc);
}
```

This works rather fine, however, it seems there might be a faster way to perform the `iloc` lookups still. What am I missing here? The `some_vector` is ordered.

Note: using the partition point to find the amount of elements that satisfy a given criterion (= what is the bin that holds a given float `el`) - there might be a faster way to go about this alltogether I'm missing here?

Comment: Are `elements` ordered, or can they be? If so, you can shrink your search space as you go along.

Comment: Interesting point. They are not originally. If they were, what would the shrinking mean exactly?

Comment: When ordered: if `element[n]`'s partition point is `5`, then we know `element[n+1]` must be larger than `5` so you can search `some_vector[5..]` instead of the whole thing.

Comment: Ah I see, good idea. Will try it out